# Calculating area of intersection between two rectangles

Tags: c#, algorithm, intersection

```
//C# Console Application Home assignment
```

I have 8 coordinates like this:

(x1, y1) (x2, y2) ... (x8, y8)
//The first 4 coordinates are for 1st rectangle
//The rest for 2nd rectangle

I store the values like this:

```
int[,] array2D = new int[8,2];
array2d[0,0] = x1;
array2d[0,1] = y1;
array2d[1,0] = x2;
array2d[1,1] = y2;
//...
array[7,0] = x8;
array[7,1] = y8;
```

I want to calculate area of intersection between those coordinates.

I already have this code to check when the rectangles aren't overlapping (it works):

```
if (!(array2D[2, 1] <= array2D[4, 1] && array2D[0, 1] >= array2D[6, 1]
                && array2D[2, 0] >= array2D[4, 0] && array2D[0, 0] <= array2D[6, 0]))
            {
//not overlapping
}
{
//overlapping
}
```

I need help with algorithm to get the area of intersection.

**NOTE:** Coordinates can have negative values.

Comment: Do you need algorithm or you are looking for function in one of the Dot Net libraries?

Comment: Algorithm or function, so i can understand and can complete my code.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [the `Rectangle.Intersect` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y10fyck0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from `System.Drawing`. There's no point in reinventing the wheel... ;-)

> Returns a third Rectangle structure that represents the intersection
>   of two other Rectangle structures. If there is no intersection, an
>   empty Rectangle is returned.

Comment: I would use that too, but I can't. It must be on this way. :)

How can I know what is the rectangle, thats my problem. After that i know I only need to do w * h of that third rectangle.

Comment: Have you tried searching for an algorithm? If it's a home assignment please state it in the question.

Comment: Yes I did, but only saw with 4 points and using rectangle class :S

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to first note that intersection of rectangles (or indeed anything) is commutative. That is, if I want to intersect A, B and C, I can intersect A and B and then intersect that with C *OR* intersect B and C and then intersect the result with A.

Therefore, store a rectangle and intersect it with successive rectangles. So you start with the first rectangle, intersect that with the second. Then you intersect the result with the third and so on.

This will give you the intersection rectangle, so you can simply compute the area.

**Update**

Your problem seems to mainly be your format for your rectangles. Namely, the 4 vertices defining the rectangle. This can easily be turned in to an X/Y for the top left and a width and height by taking the top left to be your first vertex (obviously), the width and height are the difference between this vertex and the bottom right

Comment: I think my mainly problem is to know where rectangles intersect. I only check if they intersect or not. I know how to get the area for 1 intersection, but it doesnt compute the area for all possibilities. I need help with algorithm. Changing the format of my rectangles to width, height, x y, wouldnt fix my problem, but i understand what you are saying.